# При нажатии на кнопку приложение закрывается

Tags: android

У меня приложение для заказа кофе, при нажатии на кнопки + или - происходит вылет, ошибки при этом ни какой нет, я начинаю изучать, поэтому прошу мне помочь.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="QUANTITY"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#AFACAC"
        android:onClick="increment"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price_text_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/price_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#AFACAC"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="25sp" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="PRICE"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"
        android:text="Order"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: MainActivity.java:]

Вот лог ошибок

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.justjava, PID: 4797
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.justjava.MainActivity.display(MainActivity.java:51)
        at com.example.justjava.MainActivity.increment(MainActivity.java:35)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Вылетов без ошибок не бывает - смотрите в Logcat и стек ошибки сюда. Все тексты следует прикладывать к вопросу копипастом, а не скринами. У вас в макете нет ничего с `id` `quantity_text_view`, который вы ищете в методе `display`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

У тебя в логах все написано, смотри :

> ```
>  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
> ```

```
    at com.example.justjava.MainActivity.display(MainActivity.java:51)
    at com.example.justjava.MainActivity.increment(MainActivity.java:35)
```

В методе display, 51 строчка класса MainActivity ты пытаешься вызвать метод setText() у объекта в котором null. Это значит что в 50 строчке, когда ты искал TextView c id == qantity_text_view - то такой view не нашлось и у тебя там null. Тебе надо в разметку добавить TextView с этим id (я предполагаю что  надо в самую верхнею TextView твоей xml добавить `android:id="@+id/qantity_text_view"`)

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, приложение перестало вылетать, но цена не меняется)

Comment: Конечно не будет меняться) Надо вынести из методов инкремент, декремент локальные переменный qantity и поместить ее на уровне класса. Убрать из submitOrder переменную numberOfCoffees и там тоже использовать qantity. Плюс надо сохранять как то qantity, что бы например при смене ориентации экрана данные в ней не терялись, например поместить ее во ViewModel

Comment: Оставил одну глобальную переменную quantity, убрал ее из  метода submitOrder и заменил переменную numberOfCoffee на quantity. Все получилось, все работает, спасибо Михаил)

Answer (score 0):

Знаний у меня не больше чем у вас, но так как вы на этот вопрос вряд-ли получите ещё какие-то ответы, поэтому могу лишь предположить:

1. Преобразуйте ваш `number` из типа **int** в **String** при помощи метода `String.valueof(object);`
   Выглядеть это будет примерно так:
   `quantityTextView.setText(" " +(String.valueof(number));`

Прошу обратить внимание на код который подсвечен желтым цветом у вас, скорее всего проблема в нём, не рекомендую игнорировать предупреждения компилятора так как они бывают очень полезны при выявлении ошибок, и наличие их в вашем коде уже говорит от том что он "не так хорош" как должен быть.

2. Заметил в вашем коде разметки xml отсутствие айди у нужного TextView, но в коде Main Activity он подсвечивается как имеющийся, но это скорее всего ваша ошибка при копировании кода, но на всякий случай проверьте этот момент.

Надеюсь мои скудные знания хоть немного вам помогли.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, но  теперь цена не меняется)